# how to select values from list having the order with last occurrence in c#

Tags: c#

[image]

the expected result is new list with last occurrence order.
Is it possible using the group by. Please do helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: MyList.OrderbyDescending(x => x.Index).GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.First()).ToList()

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the class deifinition and the code of the list/collection that you would like to select or order. "new list with last occurrence order" please explain more in detail what that means. We don't have the time to guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string> {"name1", "name2", "name1", "name3", "name4", "name2", "name3"};
var result = list
               .Select((value, index) => (value, index))
               .GroupBy(x => x.value)
               .Select(g => g.Last());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Obj obj0 = new() { Id = 0, Name = "name1" };
Obj obj1 = new() { Id = 1, Name = "name2" };
Obj obj2 = new() { Id = 2, Name = "name1" };
Obj obj3 = new() { Id = 3, Name = "name3" };
Obj obj4 = new() { Id = 4, Name = "name4" };
Obj obj5 = new() { Id = 5, Name = "name2" };
Obj obj6 = new() { Id = 6, Name = "name3" };

List<Obj> list = new() { obj0,obj1,obj2, obj3 , obj4 , obj5 , obj6};

var result = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).DistinctBy(p => p.Name).OrderBy(o => o.Id);

foreach (Obj obj in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
record Obj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```